# x509 chain verification which fields are sufficient

Tags: openssl, x.509

To perform the chain verfiction between rootCA, IssueCA, endentity CA which fields should be common, Note: doing through code, not from command line.
Below is the extracted part from generated certs, these are matching, are these ok or any other fields I should match.

`RootCa:
Issuer: CN = Root CA
Subject: CN = Root CA
X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
C8:30:2B:6C:2B:55:9F:F4:D1:10:66:CF:5B:69:C4:87:7C:D7:08:7D
X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
CA:TRUE`

IssueCA:
Issuer: CN = Root CA
Subject: CN = Intermediate CA
X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
7E:5E:89:FB:7A:4B:A5:5C:49:9A:7E:FA:BB:70:6B:E3:F2:AD:D9:42
X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
C8:30:2B:6C:2B:55:9F:F4:D1:10:66:CF:5B:69:C4:87:7C:D7:08:7D
X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
CA:TRUE

endentityCA:
Issuer: CN = Intermediate CA
X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
7E:5E:89:FB:7A:4B:A5:5C:49:9A:7E:FA:BB:70:6B:E3:F2:AD:D9:42

Just for more info I am printing the Hash

`//endentityca
Certificate hash: EB20023FF2E600C95B1758EAD9C09648C9BAAB99
Issuer hash: D19EDD09C8F3985F81A9166EF1F6E96FABF207F1
//Issueca
Certificate hash: 8A56AFDB22F247EB1654AE964B9A58AFF6882B6E
Issuer hash: 14E182E751107EFBF747205FFAEBD12E7E26C14D
//rootca
Certificate hash: DD01B68BF95A952DA11E41D1564FF46C3264D1D9
Issuer hash: 14E182E751107EFBF747205FFAEBD12E7E26C14D
Root CA self-signed certificate verification successful.`

Answer (score 0):

The "Authority Key Identifier" chains to the "Subject Key Identifier" of the issuer, from leaf to intermediate(s) to root. The signatures of course have to verify.

Building the chain yourself is probably a mistake, it's complicated and you should use someone else's code that already does it correctly.

Comment: Please can you elaborate more on fileds are they ok, yes I agree will reuse some verify code which exists.